# Matlab/Octave: interpolating with FIR gives scaled down signal

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, octave

Given, x(n), which is upsampled by a factor of 4, I want to interpolate it with the following code:

```matlab
pkg load signal;
n = [1:100];
x = n.*cos(n);
upsampled = upsample(x,4);
b = fir1(30,0.25,'low');
interpolated = filter(b,1,upsampled)(16:end);
figure;
stem([1:4:400],x);
hold on;
stem(interpolated);
```

The plot is:
[image]

where the original x(n) is blue and the interpolated is red.

Why is the interpolated signal scaled down?

This looks better:

```matlab
pkg load signal;
n = [1:100];
x = n.*cos(n);
upsampled = upsample(x,4);
b = fir1(30,0.25,'low');
interpolated = filter(b,1,upsampled)(16:end);
figure;
stem([1:4:400],x);
hold on;
stem(interpolated*4); %notice the multiplication by 4 here
```

[image]

But why does it work? Or was I just lucky?

Comment: If my answer helped you in solving your problem, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a clear correlation between:

```
upsample(x,4)
```

and;

```
stem(interpolated * 4)
```

`upsample` inserts 3 zeroes between each pair of values of your variable. Hence, your filter function will produce a result that is smoothed down. If your result satisfies you, it's fine. Alternatively, try to circumvent the problem like this:

```
pkg load signal;
n = 1:100;
x = n .* cos(n);
b = fir1(30,0.25,'low');
interpolated = filter(b,1,x)(4:end);
final = upsample(interpolated,4);
figure;
stem([1:4:400],x);
hold on;
stem(final);
```

Comment: How is this a correct answer when original signal is filtered and not the upsampled one?